# Editing Users With Devise and Omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, omniauth

I'm working through the Railscast on implementing Devise and OmniAuth (along with the Devise [documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3A-Overview)) -- currently, I've got a site going where visitors can sign up using their facebook accounts or by filling out a form.

I'm running into trouble when users that sign up via OmniAuth try to edit their profiles, though. Devise looks for the user's current password when they submit changes to their profiles, but those that logged in with facebook don't know their passwords (they're set automatically in the user model):

```
  def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource=nil)
    user = User.where(:provider => auth.provider, :uid => auth.uid).first
    unless user
      user = User.create(first_name:auth.extra.raw_info.first_name,
                         last_name:auth.extra.raw_info.last_name,
                           provider:auth.provider,
                           uid:auth.uid,
                           email:auth.info.email,
                           password:Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
                           )
    end
    user
  end
```

When a user edits his information, the app should not require password confirmation if he set up his account through OmniAuth. The tutorial suggests that the handy password_required? method will help me achieve this outcome. Specifically, adding this method to the user model means that it should only return true if the user didn't sign up through OmniAuth (the provider attribute would be nil in that case):

```
def password_required?
  super && provider.blank?
end
```

Thus, a piece of code like:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put }) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>
    <%= render :partial => "essential_user_info_inputs", :locals => { :f => f } %>
    <%= render :partial => "inessential_user_info_inputs", :locals => { :f => f } %>
    <% if f.object.password_required? %> 
        <%= render :partial => "password_inputs", :locals => { :f => f } %>
        <%= f.label :current_password %> <i>(we need your current password to confirm your changes)</i><br />
        <%= f.password_field :current_password %>
    <% end %>
  <%= f.submit "Update" %>
<% end %>
```

would theoretically only display password inputs when needed. It also suggests that Devise has built in logic saying that OmniAuth users don't need to use passwords to edit their accounts. I have no idea if this is true, but the tutorial kind of makes it look like that. But when an OmniAuth user tries to edit his account, I get "Current password can't be blank." Same thing with non-OmniAuth users (this makes sense, since the password fields don't show up on those users' edit pages either).

Some poking around confirms that the password_required? method is returning false, both when the user signed up through OmniAuth and through the site's regular user signup. Even when I change it to simply run the superclass method, it returns false.

Any ideas of what's going on with the password_required method? I can't find anything about it anywhere, but I feel like that's what's tripping things up right now.

#### Update:

This is now working, but not using the method outlined in the Railscast, which relies on requires_password? method, a topic that I still know nothing about. Instead, I implemented the solution outlined [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password), as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13436232/editing-users-with-devise-and-omniauth#comment18368874_13436232). So I am now only requiring passwords to update non-OmniAuth accounts with the code:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
def update
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    email_changed = @user.email != params[:user][:email]
    is_facebook_account = !@user.provider.blank?

    successfully_updated = if !is_facebook_account
      @user.update_with_password(params[:user])
    else
      @user.update_without_password(params[:user])
    end

    if successfully_updated
      # Sign in the user bypassing validation in case his password changed
      sign_in @user, :bypass => true
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You should always try to look for a gem's wiki pages. Here are Devise's: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/_pages . And here's what you are trying to do: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password

Answer (score 23):

The easiest way is to overwrite the update_resource method in your `RegistrationsController`. This is advised by devise in their own implementation of the controller:

```
  # By default we want to require a password checks on update.
  # You can overwrite this method in your own RegistrationsController.
  def update_resource(resource, params)
    resource.update_with_password(params)
  end
```

So the solution is to overwrite this method in your own controller like this:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  # Overwrite update_resource to let users to update their user without giving their password
  def update_resource(resource, params)
    if current_user.provider == "facebook"
      params.delete("current_password")
      resource.update_without_password(params)
    else
      resource.update_with_password(params)
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Simple and straight forward!. Works perfectly.

Comment: this is exactly the missing piece i was seeking. worked great.

Comment: I also added `protected` above the `update_resource` method and updated my routes to use the controller `devise_for :users, controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: "users/omniauth_callbacks", registrations: 'users/registrations' }` as per https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password

Comment: I think `current_user.provider == "facebook"` should be `resource.provider == "facebook"` current_user is not always available. For example if the user is called `current_login` or `current_user_login`. The `resource` method gets resolved to the current `@request.env['devise.mapping']`. perhaps worth changing in the answer

Answer (score 1):

I've added an update to the link below that includes my solution to the Devise/ OmniAuth change user profile/password issue and collected some helpful links:

[stackoverflow - Allowing users to edit accounts without saving passwords in devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785290/allowing-users-to-edit-accounts-without-saving-passwords-in-devise-passing-con/15346992#15346992)

Answer (score 0):

I saw this used somewhere.

```
def update
    params[:user].delete(:current_password)
    params[:user].delete(:password)
    params[:user].delete(:password_confirmation)
    if current_user.update_without_password(params[:user])
      redirect_to somewhere_wicked_path, notice => "You rock"
    else
      render 'edit', :alert => 'you roll'
    end
end
```

use something like this in your update method in your controller. Pretty sure that method is in Devise too.

Comment: Those params[:user].delete are not needed since the OP is hiding those fields in the form so they will never be sent.

Comment: sounds good. i'll update the code i stole this from and see if you are right. less code the better.