# overriding Devise update action inside omniauth_callbacks_controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

References:

```
Rails 5.0.1
omniauth 1.8.1
omniauth-facebook 5.0.0
```

I have users logged in with email + password and others with facebook account.

The main issue is to make possible to facebook's users edit their own account without needing to use the password, because they just don't have. The solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13436232/editing-users-with-devise-and-omniauth) so I can add this class:

```
  def update
    if current_user.provider == "facebook"
      params.delete("current_password")
      resource.update_without_password(user_params)
    else
      resource.update_with_password(user_params)
    end
    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

So I have this:

**routes.br**

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: "omniauth_callbacks" }
```

and inside the **omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb** I add this `update` function:

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

  def update
    if current_user.provider == "facebook"
      params.delete("current_password")
      resource.update_without_password(user_params)
    else
      resource.update_with_password(user_params)
    end
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def facebook
    user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(request.env['omniauth.auth'])
    if user.persisted?
      sign_in user
      redirect_to root_path
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, kind: 'Facebook') if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session['devise.facebook_data'] = request.env['omniauth.auth']
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :phone, :picture, :facebook_picture_url)
  end

end
```

The problem is that the devise doesn't read this function. So if we add a byebug inside it will not stop there.

The only way to override this update function is to add this configurations below.

**routes.br**

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'registrations' }
```

**registrations_controller.rb**

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def update
    if current_user.provider == "facebook"
      params.delete("current_password")
      resource.update_without_password(user_params)
    else
      resource.update_with_password(user_params)
    end
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def facebook
    user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(request.env['omniauth.auth'])
    if user.persisted?
      sign_in user
      redirect_to root_path
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, kind: 'Facebook') if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session['devise.facebook_data'] = request.env['omniauth.auth']
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :phone, :picture, :facebook_picture_url)
  end

end
```

The only problem with this second approach is that if I try to login with facebook I receive this error message:

> The action 'facebook' could not be found for
>   Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

My devise configuration:

**devise.rb**

```
Devise.setup do |config|

  config.omniauth :facebook, ENV["FB_ID"], ENV["FB_SECRET"],
    scope: 'email',
    info_fields: 'email, first_name, last_name',
    image_size: 'large',  # 50x50, guaranteed ratio
    secure_image_url: true

...

end
```

Comment: Shouldn't your `routes.rb`  file be like `devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'registrations' , omniauth_callbacks: 'omniauth_callbacks'  }`?

Comment: Yes you're right! @gasc thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case somebody else has a similar problem. The thing was that the `routes.rb` needed to specify **both** of the controllers being overwritten, like:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'registrations' , omniauth_callbacks: 'omniauth_callbacks' }
```

Comment: Maybe obvious to some people but this approach should be part of the on the omniauth documentation because it is not a particular case but really essential.